# Scale X values on achartengine

Tags: achartengine

Hello I wanted to know if it is possible to scale the X values of a XYChart, I mean, multiply each of the current X values by a factor or I have to manually replace each X value with the new values (this will include delete all the values and reload them with the new ones).

Comment: There isn't such a feature. However, maybe I can help if you describe a little bit better what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have an XYChart where I show values based on time. I change time scales so the values on X axis becomes different, right now I am deleting all the values and replacing them with the new ones, I wanted to know if there is a better approach.

Comment: I think there isn't a better one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up replacing each X value with a new one.